# Confusion about Rust HashMap and String borrowing

Tags: hashmap, rust, borrowing

This program accepts an integer N, followed by N lines containing two strings separated by a space. I want to put those lines into a `HashMap` using the first string as the key and the second string as the value:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("unable to read line");
    let desc_num: u32 = match input.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => panic!("unable to parse")
    };

    let mut map = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    for _ in 0..desc_num {
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("unable to read line");
        let data = input.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        println!("{:?}", data);
        // map.insert(data[0], data[1]);
    }
}
```

The program works as intended:

```
3
a 1
["a", "1"]
b 2
["b", "2"]
c 3
["c", "3"]
```

When I try to put those parsed strings into a `HashMap` and uncomment `map.insert(data[0], data[1]);`, the compilation fails with this error:

```
error: cannot borrow `input` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
        input.clear();
        ^~~~~
note: previous borrow of `input` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `input` until the borrow ends
        let data = input.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();
                   ^~~~~
note: previous borrow ends here
fn main() {
...
}
^
```

I don't understand why this error would come up, since I think the `map.insert()` expression doesn't borrow the string `input` at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split_whitespace()` doesn't give you two new `String`s containing (copies of) the non-whitespace parts of the input. Instead you get two references into the memory managed by `input`, of type `&str`. So when you then try to clear `input` and read the next line of input into it, you try overwriting memory that's still being used by the hash map.

Why does `split_whitespace` (and many other string methods, I should add) complicate matters by returning `&str`? Because it's often enough, and in those cases it avoid unnecessary copies. In this specific case however, it's probably best to explicitly copy the relevant parts of the string:

```
map.insert(data[0].clone(), data[1].clone());
```

Comment: Thank you @delnan! Your answer did clarify me why I would get the error. However `map.insert(data[0].clone(), data[1].clone());` doesn't work. I managed to get arround the error by changing `let mut map = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();` to `let mut map = HashMap::<String, String>::new();` and using `map.insert(data[0].to_owned(), data[1].to_owned());`. Is there a better solution which doens't involve allocating extra memory?

Comment: @B.Wang Oh sorry that was a brain fart on my part. And no, there is no good way to avoid allocating extra memory. Fundamentally, there needs to be a `String` to own the data the `&str`s point at, and it can't be `input` since that one gets overwritten repeatedly. You *could* put the `String`s into a separate vector (using `mem::replace` and an empty stirng), but this still requires allocating the vector. Note though that you won't have two copies of all data in memory, since `input` is recycled.